# Error while using Case statements in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm a beginner to Spark and I'm practicing. Could you please help me with this? It's like a capstone project for practice. This is the query I've to do.

> Apply the status to Approved if the customer is not a defaulter and credit limit applied is less than the amount spent on other cards. Apply the status to Rejected if the customer is a defaulter or credit limit applied is greater than the amount spent on other cards.

This is the data in the 2 dataframes - Credit Card Application and Customer Reference Data is provided;

[image: data]

The query I've written;

`scala> val resDF = spark.sql("SELECT ssn, cust_name, CASE WHEN cred_limit < (credit_spent1 + credit_spent2 + credit_spent3) && defaulter_flag ILIKE 'n' THEN 'Approved' WHEN cred_limit > (credit_spent1 + credit_spent2 + credit_spent3) || defaulter_flag ILIKE 'y' THEN 'Rejected' END AS status FROM credapp as ca JOIN custsref as cr ON ca.cust_name = cr.cust_name AND ca.dob = cr.dob AND ca.ssn = cr.ssn AND ca.city cr.city AND ca.state = cr.state AND ca.zipcode = cr.zipcode");`

I'm getting this error;

[image: Error]

Could you please help me with this query? I am not getting what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your case/when dont use &&/|| but stickt to and/or
2. ssn, cust_name - those are ambigous after join so you may be forced to select them as ca.snn, ca.cust_name
3. AND ca.city cr.city - here you are missing '='

I tried to reproduce it with minimal data on my env

Here is python code which creates views

```
x = [
    ("cust_name", "dob", "ssn", "mail_id", "phnone_no", "city", "state", "zipcode", "cred_limit")
]
dfx = spark.createDataFrame(x, schema=["cust_name", "dob", "ssn", "mail_id", "phnone_no", "city", "state", "zipcode", "cred_limit"])
y = [
    ("cust_name", "dob", "ssn", "city", "state", "zipcode", "existingProds", "other_banks_prod1", "credit_spent1", "other_banks_prod2", "credit_spent2", "other_banks_prod3", "credit_spent3", "defaulter_flag")
]
dfy = spark.createDataFrame(y, schema=["cust_name", "dob", "ssn", "city", "state", "zipcode", "existingProds", "other_banks_prod1", "credit_spent1", "other_banks_prod2", "credit_spent2", "other_banks_prod3", "credit_spent3", "defaulter_flag"])

dfx.createOrReplaceTempView("credapp")
dfy.createOrReplaceTempView("custsref")
```

Please check below formatted sql, syntacticaly its correct, i am able to get results

```
%sql
SELECT 
  ca.ssn, 
  ca.cust_name,
  CASE WHEN cred_limit < (
    credit_spent1 + credit_spent2 + credit_spent3
  ) AND defaulter_flag ILIKE 'n' THEN 'Approved' WHEN cred_limit > (
    credit_spent1 + credit_spent2 + credit_spent3
  ) OR defaulter_flag ILIKE 'y' THEN 'Rejected' END AS status
FROM 
  credapp as ca
  JOIN custsref as cr ON ca.cust_name = cr.cust_name 
  AND ca.dob = cr.dob 
  AND ca.ssn = cr.ssn 
  AND ca.city = cr.city 
  AND ca.state = cr.state 
  AND ca.zipcode = cr.zipcode
```

Hope it helps!